# Save data on server everyday

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am working on an app in which i have to save some data on server everyday. I am using `UILocalNotification` for this purpose. But using this the data is saved only when i click on the notification that is presented. Is there any way to save data on server without clicking on the notification that presents even when the app is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use "[silent notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)" to wake up your app in background, and make it upload the needed data, still in background without worrying the user.

Comment: can i use alarm +event to do so

Comment: No, silent notifications are sent by an Apple Push News Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. UILocalNotification can only present an alert in the notification center, and your custom actions are **not** executed until the user taps the alert.

An alternative would be to use **background fetch** feature introduced in iOS 7. [Here is a little reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)

Comment: @Fuija -Does background fetch is used to post data or it is used just to fetch?

Comment: @Ankit, although its name suggests *fetch*, you can actually do anything as long as you keep the duration short. In your case, uploading data is no difference than downloading data as seen by the system.